# Will 11.04 ship with Nautilus 3?

Tags: 11.04, nautilus

Will Ubuntu 11.04 contain new, redesigned Nautilus 3 from GNOME 3 ?

Answer (score 8):

Not likely, according to this [status report](https://lists.ubuntu.com/archives/ubuntu-desktop/2011-January/002740.html), GNOME 2.32 will be shipped in 11.04.