# Will nautilus be replaced as the default file manager in 11.04?

Tags: nautilus, 11.04

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Nautilus 3 in Natty](https://askubuntu.com/questions/22337/nautilus-3-in-natty)

I want to know if Nautilus will change or be replaced in Natty Narwhal? If so to what?

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by constant?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, Ubuntu 11.04 contains nautilus and it's the same as Ubuntu 10.10 release. The move to Unity has not effected the release or use of nautilus to show files and folders.

Yet.